# Are mosquitos attracted to farts?

Tags: entomology

According to [wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mosquito), female mosquitos (the ones that bite) use the protein in our blood to provide nutrition for their eggs.

I was lying in bed the other day with mosquito's bothering me, and had one coming. So I thought, *this* will teach these no-good insects to be bothering me! But then it struck me that they might actually like it because of the protein.

Since they're after the protein in our blood, and I'd imagine that a fart is a very creamy soup of proteins indeed, maybe it won't chase them away.

So I held it in. Did I do the right thing?

Comment: Lol farts are not a creamy soup of protein. http://www.oddee.com/item_98612.aspx

Comment: "I'd imagine that a fart is a very creamy soup of proteins" you sure you're talking about fart here? ;)

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because we are trying to maintain a scientific stack. Far fetched trivial questions on gaseous (or other rearward O.o) output do not belong here imo.

Comment: It is scientific. Just because it is an often humorized subject does NOT invalidate its scientific significance. Why the downvote?

Comment: This is a biology forum - It's only natural that such subjects will occur now and then. And what's the point of using unfamiliar terms like 'flatulence' which nobody uses or understands anyways? @AliceD

Comment: @MarcoPrins do you mean, in a way, why do we call brain as 'encephalon' even if no layman uses or understands it anyways? Anyways, I downvoted because the base of your question "I'd imagine that a fart is a very creamy soup of proteins" is wrong.

Comment: If you rewrote the question with a ton more maturity AND demonstrated that you've done some previous  research of your own (i.e., determining that farts aren't creamy protein soups),  then i  would  consider this  question  on topic. See [here](http://biology.stackexchange.com/help/how-to-ask)  for tips on  writing  good questions on our site.

Comment: I confess. I didn't really hold it in.

Answer (score 6):

Apart for the fact that your question is deeply strange, I will try to reply to you.

Mosquitoes are attracted by several factors that make them able to recognize their prey; two of these are: Warm bodies and CO2.

CO2 is the product of your mitochondrial respiration, when you breath out from your lungs you expel liters of this gas.  This is how mosquitoes understand that you are alive. You are warm and you breath !

One of the devices used to kill mosquitoes is in fact a giant vacum  cleaner that warms up till 37°C and emits CO2, by burning gas.

Going forward with your question: Let's speak about farts. 
Farts are not "a soup of proteins". Farts are gasses (mostly methane) and CO2 produced by bacterias during the decomposition of the food that you ingest. That is also why your excrements smells more when you don't poop for a long time. They fermented more :P.

So, since it is true that part of a fart is composed by CO2 and they produce a warm cloud around you, I would say YES, they do attract female mosquitoes. But so do you. So release your gasses, or stop to breath at all.

Hope I've replied to all your doubts. 
Cheers

I didn't know we were peer-reviewed. 
Here my references.

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Flatulence .

[https://www.amazon.com/Lehninger-Principles-Biochemistry-Fourth-Nelson/dp/0716743396](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/0716743396)   .

http://labs.russell.wisc.edu/mosquitosite/preventing-mosquito-bites/carbon-dioxide-baited-mosquito-traps/ .

A biologist.

Comment: Please add some references to your answer.